# using keypress and click for submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make a click event and keypress work in the same if statement?

Right now I have :

```
if($('.test').is(':visible;)){
   $('button').click(function(e){
      ..do something here
    }else {
     ..do something here
 });
```

.test is the value field that when the user puts in the value I want them to be able to click the enter key, while they are in this box to submit the information or use the button to do so. This is not in a form, they are all in divs.

Comment: there's something wrong with syntax in your statement. If you need to call the same logic from two events handlers, then just create separate method, and bind it for both events. Simple as it is.

Comment: You mean so that `$('button').click()` and `$('.test').keypress()` both run the same function?

Comment: You should wrap it in a form and use the submit handler of the form...

Comment: i would also strongly suggest putting this in a `<form>`. It will let you just listen to `form.submit()` and I believe not putting them in is _technically_ invalid HTML. is there anything really stopping you from doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So put the logic into a common function and call it for click and keypress.

```js
    (function () {
    
       function yourLogic () {
         $(".out").text($(".yourInput").val());
       }
    
       $("button").on("click", yourLogic);
       $(".yourInput").on("keyup", function (evt) {
           if (evt.which===13) yourLogic();
       });
    
    }());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="yourInput" />
<button>Click</button>
<div class="out"></div>
```

or do not use a common function and call the click() event on the button.

```
   $(".yourInput").on("keyup", function (evt) {
       if (evt.which===13) $("#yourButton").trigger("click");
   });
```

Comment: FYI `.keyCode` is deprecated!  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: jQuery normalizes it so not a big deal until they remove it.

Comment: @epascarello It normalizes `event.which`, not keycode AFAIK

Comment: it said that this $("button").on("click", yourLogic); is not a function

Comment: @Keith So what did you do differently than the code above?

Comment: i know what happened, i put the bottom code within the function, let me try it onw

Comment: it doesnt recognize yourLogic as a function in this part $('button').on('click', yourLogic);, it says its not defined

Comment: I just updated the code with an example showing that it works. Guessing you have the function in a different scope than the event handers in however you implemented it.

Comment: I had to switch out .on ('click' with just .click, thanks for the help!

Comment: Wha version of jQuery are you using that does not work with on()? Under the covers, click() calls .on()

Answer (score 1):

If you got a form, then bind [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your event handler here
});
```

It will be triggered when you press enter to submit the form, and when you click submit button at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply click on background

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('button').trigger("click");
    }
});

//if($('.test').is(':visible;)){
   $('button').on("click",function(e){
      alert("click or enter");
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
//   }
 //  else {
  //   ..do something here
   //}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLick me</button>
```